# How to display tree on web site?

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I'm looking for jQuery plugin or something that helps to display:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
  /       \
 4         5
         /   \
        6     7
       /  \
      8    9
```

Any tips?

P.s. W/o silverlight/flash magic. No problems with CSS3/Html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://frank-mich.com/jQuery/

Comment: Nice. Will wait a bit though. Answered questions catches less eyes. :)